# De-synonymize [cmake] and [cmake-gui]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-removal-request

Suddenly I found that my favorite tag - [cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmake) - has a [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?search=cmake-gui) [cmake-gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmake-gui). Name of the latter tag perfectly fits to [cmake-gui](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-gui.1.html) tool, which is a GUI wrapper around command-line configuration tool called `cmake`.

While `cmake-gui` is *about* CMake language and `cmake` configuration process, the opposite is not necessary true:

1. Not every usage of CMake implies usage of `cmake-gui`. Actually, most users prefer to use `cmake` tool directly.
2. When write `CMakeLists.txt`, one rarely thinks about its GUI representation. But many commonly used CMake functions automatically affects on GUI in a nice way.

Following are examples of questions specifically about CMake GUI. That is, they won't arise without using `cmake-gui` tool:

1. [Why my CMake GUI looks different than usual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61411077/why-my-cmake-gui-looks-different-than-usual)
2. [How to get cmake command line arguments from running GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74277997/how-to-get-cmake-command-line-arguments-rom-running-gui)
3. [Using Cmake-gui and vcpkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47413392/using-cmake-gui-and-vcpkg)
4. [Cmake-gui not coming up on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59701307/cmake-gui-not-coming-up-on-windows)

They still retain* [cmake-gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmake-gui) tag, but, because of synonym mark, cannot be searched by that tag.

Of course, there are questions (e.g. [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73500120/why-is-cmake-gui-not-setting-environment-variables-like-it-should)) tagged with `cmake-gui`, but where GUI is not an essential part.
But I don't expect such mis-tagging to become a massive one, so it can be handled as any other mis-tagging (that is, by editing).

While CMake GUI is not as popular as CMake itself (251 vs. 26382 according to [synonyms tab](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?search=cmake-gui)), I think it deserves its **own tag** [cmake-gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmake-gui).

---

*I don't get why `cmake-gui` tag remains on some questions. According to the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work), this may occur only when a question had been tagged **before** synonymizing, but e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73500120/why-is-cmake-gui-not-setting-environment-variables-like-it-should) has been created in 2022, which is 5 years **after** creating the synonym.

Comment: To answer the closing statement, I believe the "created" date is the date the synonym *suggestion* was created, not the date it was made a synonym; as some synonyms literally take years to be voted on, the  this can make for a big disparity between the created date, and the implementation date. If this is the correct understanding, I admit it is misleading.

Comment: ^ That's also what I understood. There's even [a question tagged on 2 Feb, 2023](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75324090/how-to-actually-use-c-nana), so it was approved very recently.

Comment: It was approved this week as it had a score of 2 at the weekend: [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1708942?TagName=cmake)

Comment: I've removed the synonym. There were no renames at the time of removal so no questions would have been mistagged due to the synonym.

Comment: It might be nice if someone could populate the wiki excerpt for [tag:cmake-gui] to indicate it's about the tool specifically. The excerpt is more visible than the wiki is.

Comment: @HenryEcker I just submitted an edit. TIL that 5k rep doesn't mean I can bypass peer review for tag edits. (I just got to 5k recently and this was my first tag edit since)

Comment: @user: Looks like that comes with the "[trusted user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)" privilege (which is earned at 20k rep on SO): "Editing tag wikis without needing approval"